# Prevent default Telerik sort for RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, sorting, telerik

I am using Telerik RadGrid and I have a data source where one of my columns look like hh:mm:ss. When I load the datasource of the RadGrid from the database I order the results (on SQL level) based on a DateTime column (which contains year, month and day too), but in the grid representation I am showing just hh:mm:ss. My custom sort on SQL level is working well, in a given page I get exactly those elements which should be there. However, when I sort a column which is essentially a DateTime but is represented as hh:mm:ss, default telerik sort also occurs which sorts the rows in the given page. This is incorrect, because '09-12-2012 20:20:20' < '09-13-2012 10:10:10', but '20:20:20' > '10:10:10'. How can I prevent default telerik sort for my RadGrid? I want everything else to work in the same way, I just want to tell Telerik "do not sort my column, I've already handled the sort event, thanks". How can I achieve this?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ID" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
            <CommandItemTemplate>
                <div class="cmdItem">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnManageColumns" runat="server" CommandName="Manage Columns" data-link="manage-columns">
                        <img alt="" src="../../Images/Icons/Columns.png" />Manage Columns</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSpacer" runat="server" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExportPDF" runat="server" CommandName="Export PDF"
                        OnClientClick="return exportGrid('PDF');"><img alt="" src="../../Images/Icons/ExportPDF.png" />Export to PDF</asp:LinkButton>&#160;&#160;&#160;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendEmail" runat="server" CommandName="SendEmail" OnClientClick="return exportGrid('PDFEmail');"><img alt="" src="../../Images/Icons/PasswordSetup.png"/>Email</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </CommandItemTemplate>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnCommand="gridCommand" />
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" UseClientSelectColumnOnly="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AllowCustomSorting="true"
```

This attribute should be added to the MasterTableView tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn off the sort for a column, or the whole grid if that's what you want

per column

```
<Columns>
        <tr:GridBoundColumn DataField="field" HeaderText="Description" 
             AllowSorting="false" />
    </Columns>
```

whole grid

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridData" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" OnNeedDataSource="RadGridData_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RadGridData_ItemDataBound">
```

For Custom Sorting

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" OnSortCommand="RadGrid1_SortCommand" >
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew Walters, but I am afraid you didn't understand the question. I want to allow sorting as event but I want to run my sort instead of Telerik's sort. Your suggestion disables the sort feature altogether, so your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In fact the problem is that my (correct) sort is executed and after that Telerik messes up everything with its default sort.

Comment: Do you have a OnSortCommand="SortCommand_Event"  in your radGrid definition?

You should post up your radgrid code.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question. As you can see there is no SortCommand_Event defined. I've tried that event too, but I didn't achieve success.

Comment: I think you need to add in OnSortCommand="SortCommand_Event" where SortCommand_event is your custom sorting event

See this link for more detailed example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/sort/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I've tried with e.Canceled = True, but this didn't prevent the default sort of Telerik. I only want to disable the default sort.